# TSQL Iterate subsets within a table - Updating values according to group

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I have a large table that includes groups of records.
I need to make changes to the internal group IDs - I want to run this process for each group seperatly

Example data

```
Index  Group    InternalID  Data
001    01       01       
002    01       02      
003    01       03      Split
004    01       04
005    02       01       
006    02       02      Split
007    02       03
008    02       04
009    02       05
100    03       01       
101    03       02
102    03       03
103    03       04      Split
104    03       05
```

For each group, I need to do the following:

1. Get the number of records of that group (N)
2. Get the position of the record with the 'Split' data (S)
3. Change the ID's up to the Split position to be Original+N
4. Add two rows to each group with ID's Split+N+1 and Split+N+2
5. Change the Id's after the split to Original+N+2

The end result should be

```
Group        InternalID      Data
01           05
01           06
01           07              Split
01           08              NewItem1
01           09              NewItem2
01           10              
02           06
02           07              Split
02           08              NewItem1
02           09              newItem2
02           10 
02           11
02           12
03           06
03           07
03           08
03           09              Split
03           10              NewItem1
03           11              NewItem2
03           12
```

I imagine it to look like [Beware pseudocode!!! Not real SQL!]

```
Declare @GCount VARCHAR(10)
    @GSplit VARCHAR(10)

CREATE TABLE ##temp (
    Idx int,
    Grp int,
    InternalID int, 
    Data varchar (10)

FOREACH [Group] from [Example]

        Select @GCount = COUNT(InternalID)
        Select @GSplit = (select InternalID from [Example] where [Data]='Split')
        Insert Into ##temp 
            Select Grp, Data,
            CASE WHEN InternalID <= @GSplit THEN InternalID + @GCount
            ELSE THEN InternalID+@GCount+2
            END AS InternalID
        INSERT INTO ##temp 
            VALUES (00,[Group],@GSplit + @GCount + 1, 'NewItem1'),  (01,[Group],@GSplit + @GCount + 2, 'NewItem2')
 END FOREACH

UPDATE  
    [Example]
SET 
    [Example].* = ##temp.*
FROM 
    ##temp
OUTER JOIN
    [Example]
ON
    ##temp.Idx=[Example].Idx


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##temp') IS NOT NULL

BEGIN

    Drop Table ##temp

END
)
```

I know the above does not exist as-is, but how can I get the same functionality?

Comment: Perhaps showing the results that you want would help another person understand the question (note:  I did not downvote the question).

Comment: I've updated the post accordingly. I wished people would explain why they downvote... I worked hard to phrase the question correctly :(

Comment: Is there guaranteed to be exactly one split?

Comment: @Paparazzi - yes, there should be only one split

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find out where the split is, and how big the groups are, using windows functions.

Add in the new rows, based off of the split rows.  This ensures you know what id's to apply, and also to only add rows where the actually is a split.

Use arithmetic and `CASE` to work out the correct id values.

```
WITH
  summarised AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    MAX([InternalID])
      OVER (PARTITION BY [group])                             AS GroupMaxID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN [data] = 'split' THEN [InternalID] END)
      OVER (PARTITION BY [group])                             AS GroupSplitID
  FROM
    yourData
)
SELECT
  [group],
  GroupMaxID
    + InternalID
    + CASE WHEN InternalID > GroupSplitID THEN 2 ELSE 0 END   AS InternalID,
  [data]
FROM
  summarised

UNION ALL

SELECT
  summarised.[group],
  summarised.GroupMaxID
    + summarised.InternalID
    + NewRows.Offset,
  NewRows.datum
FROM
  summarised
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT 1 AS offset, 'NewItem1' AS datum
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS offset, 'NewItem2' AS datum
)
  AS NewRows
WHERE
  summarised.[data] = 'split'

ORDER BY
  1, 2
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/91d7c/3

***EDIT:***

Slightly shorter and more consistent implementation of the same logic:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d56f1/1

Very marginally faster too.

```
WITH
  summarised AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    MAX([InternalID])
      OVER (PARTITION BY [group])                             AS GroupMaxID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN [data] = 'split' THEN [InternalID] END)
      OVER (PARTITION BY [group])                             AS GroupSplitID
  FROM
    yourData
)
SELECT
  summarised.[group]           AS [group],
  summarised.GroupMaxID
    + summarised.InternalID
    + NewRows.Offset           AS InternalID,
  NewRows.[data]               AS [data]
FROM
  summarised
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT 0 AS offset, summarised.[data] WHERE summarised.InternalID <= summarised.GroupSplitID
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 AS offset, 'NewItem1'        WHERE summarised.InternalID  = summarised.GroupSplitID
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS offset, 'NewItem2'        WHERE summarised.InternalID  = summarised.GroupSplitID
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS offset, summarised.[data] WHERE summarised.InternalID >  summarised.GroupSplitID
)
  AS NewRows
ORDER BY
  summarised.[group],
  summarised.InternalID,
  NewRows.Offset
```

Comment: Great! I've inserted the last two selects with "INSERT INTO" another table - and got the end result. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do it

```
declare @t table (idx int, grp int, id int, data varchar(10));
insert into @t values  
       (001,    01,       01, null)      
     , (002,    01,       02, null)          
     , (003,    01,       03, 'Split')
     , (004,    01,       04, null)    
     , (005,    02,       01, null)           
     , (006,    02,       02, 'Split')
     , (007,    02,       03, null)    
     , (008,    02,       04, null)    
     , (009,    02,       05, null)    
     , (100,    03,       01, null)           
     , (101,    03,       02, null)    
     , (102,    03,       03, null)    
     , (103,    03,       04, 'Split')
     , (104,    03,       05, null);
with cte as 
(  select t.* 
        , count(*)     over (partition by t.grp) as cnt 
        , row_number() over (partition by t.grp order by t.id, t.idx) as rn 
        , (count(*) over (partition by t.grp) + t.id) as nwId  
        , ts.id as 'split' 
        , CASE WHEN t.id > ts.id THEN (count(*) over (partition by t.grp) + t.id + 2) 
                                 ELSE (count(*) over (partition by t.grp) + t.id) 
               end as nwnwId
     from @t t
     left join @t ts 
       on ts.grp = t.grp 
      and ts.data = 'split' 
)
select t.* 
 from cte t  
union all 
select t.idx, t.grp, t.id, null, t.cnt, t.rn, t.nwId, t.split, t.nwnwId + 1
 from cte t 
where t.data = 'split'
union all 
select t.idx, t.grp, t.id, null, t.cnt, t.rn, t.nwId, t.split, t.nwnwId + 2
 from cte t 
where t.data = 'split'
 order by grp, nwnwId, idx;
```

Comment: The output for each group should have two additional rows (with the new items).

Comment: @MatBailie See first line.  "Not complete but about 1/2 way there"

Comment: @Paparazzi The OVER PARTITION was an eye opener - I did not know this function. also the WITH is used in a different way than "classroom" solutions. Thanks.